# Check when a system alert is shown in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following usecase.
I want to show an overlay over the current window when the application moves to the task manager.
Currently I am doing the following:

```
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        guard let window = application.keyWindow else { return }
        ApplicationPrivacyProtector.showOverlay(inKeyWindow: window)
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        guard let window = application.keyWindow else { return }
        ApplicationPrivacyProtector.hideOverlay(inKeyWindow: window)
    }
```

This works fine but 
**applicationWillResignActive** is also called when a system alert (eg. faceID, touchID, etc.) is shown which triggers this overlay view as well. 
Is there a way to distinguish between **system alert** and **application moves to taskmanager**?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find a sophisticated solution.
What I am doing now, is  showing the overlay only when the user is logged in and not on the login where Face ID is triggered. 
This meets our requirement that no sensitive data is shown in the taskmanager.